# Evaluate $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sin^n\left(\frac{2\pi n}{3n+1}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to solve this limit rigorously

> $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sin^n\left(\frac{2\pi n}{3n+1}\right)$

I can see that the answer is $0$ as
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin\left(\frac{2\pi n}{3n+1}\right) = \sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \lt 1$$
But this solution doesn't seem rigorous and I'm unable to come up with a rigorous approach

Comment: You're right, it's not rigorous, because what you're ultimately trying to claim is that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \big[ f(n) \big]^n
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left[ \lim_{m \to \infty} f(m) \right]^n
$$
but this need not be the case. A simple example to that effect is the sequence
$$
a_n = 1 + \frac 1 n
$$
We know that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac 1 n \right)^n = e
$$
[cont.]

Comment: but
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \lim_{m \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac 1 m \right) \right)^n = 1
$$
Generally, one needs to be mindful of this -- of what amounts to trying to pull $n$ outside of a limit that involves $n$ approaching something.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For $n>2$,
$$
\pi>\frac{2\pi}{3}>\frac{2\pi n}{3n+1}>\frac{2\pi n}{3n+n/2}=\frac{4\pi}{7}>\frac{\pi}{2},
$$
so for $n>2$,
$$
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}=\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)<\sin\left(\frac{2\pi n}{3n+1}\right)<\sin\left(\frac{4\pi}{7}\right)<1.
$$
Thus,
$$
0=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^n\le \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sin\left(\frac{2\pi n}{3n+1}\right)\right)^n\le \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sin\left(\frac{4\pi}{7}\right)\right)^n=0,
$$
so
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sin\left(\frac{2\pi n}{3n+1}\right)\right)^n=0.
$$

Answer (score 5):

To do it rigorously first say that since $a_n=\sin(\frac{2n\pi}{3n+1})\to \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, for all large $n$ , $0<a_n\leq c <1$.

Hence $(a_n)^n\leq c^n$ for all large $n$ and as the right hand side goes to $0$, you have the desires result that the original sequence goes to $0$

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$A_n=\left(\sin\left(\frac{2\pi n}{3n+1}\right)\right)^n \quad \implies \quad \log(A_n)=n \log\left(\sin\left(\frac{2\pi n}{3n+1}\right)\right)$$
Using Taylor series
$$\sin\left(\frac{2\pi n}{3n+1}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{\pi }{9 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
$$\log\left(\sin\left(\frac{2\pi n}{3n+1}\right)\right)=-\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)+\frac{2 \pi }{9
   \sqrt{3} n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
$$\log(A_n)=-\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)n+\frac{2 \pi }{9  \sqrt{3}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
$$A_n=e^{\log(A_n) }=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)n+\frac{2 \pi }{9  \sqrt{3}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)  \right)$$